# Is the Big O notation of nested dependent for loop always n^2

Tags: loops, for-loop, language-agnostic

Is the Big O notation of nested dependent for loop always O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for worst-case complexity. But only if the length /step of the inner loop == length /step of the outer loop.

Comment: This is not correct. The key is that the step, or increment, follows the same function(of same degree) for both.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation stands for Upper bound. So for a `dependent for loop` consider following example :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
```

Can be modified to:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

Which means you have two loops running for n-times, making the upper bound as n^2. Hence the big-O notation as O(n^2)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily. It depends on the algorithm.

E.g. a "group by" semantic basically processes the groups in the outer loop while the group items are processed in an (nested) inner loop. But at the end of the day every item is processed only exactly once. With a hashed grouping algorithm it might be only O(n).

So the general answer to your question is **no**.